# How to get d3 map to refresh with new saved data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have built a map that has all the states and counties in the map. Within the map I have some counties that are associated with basins. I allow the user to add new basins to the map, but after the user saves the new basin it doesn't show up in the legend. I redraw the map function and clear the legend before redrawing the legend as well. But again the new info doesn't show up until after I fully refresh the page.

Here is where I first draw the map:

```
      function drawMap() {
            //DRAW MAP
            d3.json("js/map.json", function(error, mapData){
                if (error) throw error;

                //draw counties
                map.svg.append("g")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.counties).features)
                    .enter().append("path");

                //draw county-borders
                map.svg.append("path")
                    .datum(topojson.mesh(mapData, mapData.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a!==b; }))
                    .attr("class", "countylines borders")
                    .attr("d", map.path);
                //draw state-borders
                map.svg.append("path")
                    .datum(topojson.mesh(mapData, mapData.objects.states, function(a, b) { return true; }))
                    .attr("class", "states borders")
                    .attr("d", map.path);
               }
        }
```

And here is where I draw the legend:

```
          function drawMapLegend() {
                $("#mapLegend").empty();
                $("#paddLegend").empty();
                $("#subLegend").empty();
                // Create map legend svg layer for Basins
                var basinLen = basin.length;
                map.legendBasin = d3.select("#mapLegendDiv").append("div")
                    .attr("id", "mapLegend")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("height", 750)
                    .attr("style", "width:100%;")
                    .append("g");
                //display basin names in the legend
                for(i=0;i<basin.length;i++) {
                    map.legendBasin.append("text")
                        .attr("x", 15).attr("y", (i*16)+20)
                        .attr("class", "basinText")
                        .text(basin["BasinName"][i]);
                 }
           }
```

After saving I update the array-like object with the new basin array. I know that works bc I console.log the response before and after saving and it shows the new basin. How can I get the map to refresh to show the new basin in the legend? After the save I call drawMapLegend();

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of D3's data binding approach. Mike Bostock has [great](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#data) [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data) explaining how it works. First one is somewhat outdated but still explain things clearly.

Bind the basin array to the "map.legendBasin" selection and then when you update the basin array, you can just use the enter() selection to append the new elements.

You would do something like the following:

```
map.legendBasin
   .data(basin, function(d){return d;})//join using key
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .attr("x", 15)....//etc whatever stuff you want
```

Notice that this code is reusable for both the first time and when new elements come in. When the new array comes you can simply call this function again and only the new elements will get created as the key will match for the existing elements while it would not for the new elements hence the enter() selection will contain only the data not already appended as an element in the DOM. You may use the exit() selection in case you have to remove elements.